# entire clickable <div> with nested divs

Tags: css, html-lists, href, clickable

What I'm trying to do is to change the background color on the whole "row" div on mouse over and open the href link clicking on any part of the div. I have tried all the solutions I found on SO (both with jquery and pure css) but I can't get it working

Here is my code:

HTML

```
    <div id="row">
        <div class="document-date"><?php the_time('d-m-Y') ?></div>
        <div class="document-category"><img src="/images/icon.png" /></div>
        <div class="document-title"><a href="myurl..." target="_blank">My link</a>
        <p>some description</p>
   </div>
```

And the CSS

```
#row {

    position: relative;
    width: 700px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 10px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

#row:hover {

    background: #fbf5d8;
}


.document-date{

    float: left;
    color: #1b6392;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    line-height: 35px;

}

.document-category{

    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    line-height: 35px;

}

.document-title {

    width: 350px;
    float: left;
    color: #020100;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-top: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.document-title a{

    width: 350px;
    float: left;
    color: #020100;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}

.document-title a:hover{

    color: #fff;

}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't even see a `li` element there o.O

Comment: there is no `li` in your example code.

Comment: You mean the `<div id="row">`?

Comment: My fault...sorry guys! I started with another example that was a li, then changed to this. Edited the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming when you say `li`, you mean `div#row`

CSS:

```
#row:hover {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

JavaScript (using jQuery):

```
$('#row').click(function() {
  // do something
  // example:
  $(this).find('a:first').click();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Erick I had already tried this one, but it's not working. Nothing changes, probably there is some mess in my CSS. I have posted it.

Comment: solved adding live: `$("#row").live("click", function() {
 window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
      return false;
});`

Comment: @Andycap So, you are injecting the html code from JavaScript, or you forget about adding the `$(document).ready` before the jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <div id="row" onclick="alert(1)">
        <div class="document-date" >12-08-2014</div>
        <div class="document-category" ><img src="/images/icon.png" /></div>
        <div class="document-title" ><a href="myurl..." target="_blank" >My link</a><br/><p>some description</p>
   </div>​
```

This would do the trick.
Or if you want the divs separately

```
<div id="row">
        <div class="document-date"  onclick="alert(1)">12-08-2014</div>
        <div class="document-category" onclick="alert(1)" ><img src="/images/icon.png" /></div>
        <div class="document-title"  onclick="alert(1)"><a href="myurl..." target="_blank" >My link</a><br/><p>some description</p>
   </div>​
```